# Trying to get downloadable url of the SharePoint file of the attachments shared in the teams/channel chat

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

**We are trying to access the SharePoint url of the attachments shared in the teams/channel chat and for the teams meeting recording.**
We have used Oauth2 to retrieve the auth token and using Microsoft graph api to get the downloadable/public url for the same
making a GET request with token in the request header still returns 401 Unauthorised error
Although we are able to get the downloadable url if we use site-id , list-id  and item-id in the GET request [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item}/driveitem](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/lists/%7Blist-id%7D/items/%7Bitem%7D/driveitem)
But these are not available when our message extension app is invoked from a message

Comment: Hi @Punit Gupta, Using Graph API explorer are you able to get the drive item with this API https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/lists/%7Blist-id%7D/items/%7Bitem%7D/driveitem ? Or you are getting error?

Comment: Any update? @Punit Gupta

Comment: Are you still facing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Posting the Answer for better knowledge**

**Copying from @Saonti comments**

Using Graph API explorer are you able to get the drive item with this API graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/lists/… ? Or you are getting error?